# IE11 - Getting a webpage to STOP showing in Enterprisemode

Tags: internet-explorer-11

This is an odd question, in that I'm not trying to display a page in EnterpriseMode - I'm trying to prevent it from displaying in EnterpriseMode. I'm assisting the Webserver team, so my access is limited to only changes in the page itself.

The twist is that the rest of the domain has to be displayed in EnterpriseMode, save for this one page.

I've tried utilizing an XML document and changing HKLM\software\microsoft\internet explorer\main\enterprisemode -- setting SiteList to my file location on the local machine, and Enabled to blank. The page ignores this and loads itself into EnterpriseMode anyways.

Example of my Site.XML. Note: I've changed the server name to protect the innocent. Also I'm having to use the escape characters so the note quits trying to interact with my example. I could've sworn code block should've stopped that.

```
<rules version="1">
<emie>
<domain exclude="false">internalportal.ExampleServer.com<path exclude="true">/OperationsRecap/</path></domain>
</emie>
</rules>
```

I've tried the same thing in the HKCU key, and even checked gredit for anything that might be pushing it to default. No such luck. This should be a fairly simple procedure, but it's stumping me. I'm starting to wonder if the Webserver team has a customHeader stuck in web.config, but I don't have access and I've been waiting for an answer from them for a few days now. And by 'waiting' I mean 'continually hounding'.

Compatibility mode doesn't seem to make a difference, whether its on or off. I've several sites with different settings that get the same problem - and then several sites with different settings that do not get that problem. There does not appear to be a rhyme or reason in terms of configuration on the local machines. So while it's tempting to call it an issue with IIS7 web.config and dust my hands of the whole thing, I have to be absolutely certain.

I've dug at the source code, and literally the only difference is in the META tag. Those that load correctly load X-UA-Compatible as IE=Edge, like they're supposed too. Those that do not load as IE=8, despite all my attempts to force them to stop that. In fact, when it fails to load I can go to tools on the IE11, de-select EnterpriseMode, and it reloads just fine. The META tag changes as well in the source. Again, whether compatibility mode is on or off, whether there's a list in play, utterly ignoring any changes I make to EnterpriseMode key.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I was looking in HKLM\software\microsoft\internet explorer\main\EnterpriseMode

I should have been looking in hklm\software\policies\microsoft\internet explorer\main\EnterpriseMode

Lesson learned, stupid mistake.